# how to display database data in tables in view in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application am retrieving data from Database. I want to display the retired data in tables. 
controller code:

```
 public ActionResult MyAccount()
    {

        var user = User.Identity.Name;

       string sThumbnails = "";

        DataSet dsTemplates = new DataSet();

        string qryTemplets = "select * from FileInfo where UserName= '" + user + "'";

        open_Connection();
        SqlDataAdapter daTemplate = new SqlDataAdapter(qryTemplets, conn);
        daTemplate.Fill(dsTemplates, "FileInfo");
        DataTable dtTemplates = new DataTable();
        dtTemplates = dsTemplates.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow row in dtTemplates.Rows)
        {

            sThumbnails = sThumbnails +  row["FileName"] +  row["Date"] +  row["Time"] +  row["Info"] ;
            ViewData["thumbs"] = sThumbnails;
        }
        close_Connection();
        return View();
    }
```

view code:

```
    <div id="formleft" style="border-style: solid; border-color: inherit; border-width: 4px; width:550px; height:500px; position:absolute; top: 345px; left: 348px;">
   <h2 class="heading" style="text-align: center;">Info</h2><%= ViewData["thumbs"] %> </div>
```

This code displays the data But i want to display it in tabular format.

How can i display the data in tabular format?

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Displaying-DataTables-in-Asp-Net-MVC-Razor-Page

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `ViewData`, use a Model built using a custom class to store that information. Something like:

```
public class TableInfo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; } //you might want to change this to DateTime
    public string Time { get; set; }  //this may need changing to TimeSpan or int possibly?
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<TableInfo> tables = dtTemplates.Rows.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(t => new TableInfo
        {
            FileName = row["FileName"],
            Date = row["Date"],
            Time = row["Time"],
            Info = row["Info"]
        })
    .ToList();

    close_Connection();
    return View(tables);
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
@model List<TableInfo>

if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>File Name</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Info</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (TableInfo item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FileName</td>
                <td>@item.Date</td>
                <td>@item.Time</td>
                <td>@item.Info</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Am getting error for .Select(t => new FileInfo as: 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: One more thing is FileInfo table from database contains record of all the users. I want to display the data of the logged in user only. Am developing this application in MVC2

Comment: ah you'll need to use `Rows.AsEnumerable()`. Make sure you add `using System.Linq;` too.

Comment: Can you provide me the full code.. I am still confused. I want it urgent. so please

Comment: @pihu Check my updated edit. You need to do `Rows.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: If i use Rows.AsEnumerable I am getting error as System.Data.DataRowCollection does not contain definition for AsEnumerable

Answer (score -2):

Add follow code Before Html Code in your Model

```
<style> 
   table th {  border: 1px solid black; text-align:center }
   table td {  border: 1px solid black; text-align:center } 
  </style>
```