# How to implement paging in an MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I have an mvc app using razor files cshtml and I would like to implement paging. There is an example of getting the table data displayed at this link:
[how to display database data in tables in view in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168648/how-to-display-database-data-in-tables-in-view-in-mvc).

I would like to know how I can add paging to the example as provided in the answer ?

Comment: see :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

Comment: [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)